# ORDER BY Alias not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

UPDATING QUESTION:

```
ERROR:  column "Fruits" does not exist
```

Running Postgres 7.4(Yeah we are upgrading)

Why can't I ORDER BY the column alias? wants tof."TypeOfFruits" in the ORDER BY as well, why?

```
SELECT (CASE
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'A' THEN 'Apple' 
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'P' THEN 'Pear' 
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'G' THEN 'Grapes' 
    ELSE 'Other' END) AS "Fruits",
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.order_date 
        BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('DAY', LOCALTIMESTAMP) AND DATE_TRUNC('DAY', LOCALTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1 DAY' 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS daily, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.order_date 
        BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', LOCALTIMESTAMP) AND DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', LOCALTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS monthly, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.order_date 
        BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', LOCALTIMESTAMP) AND DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', LOCALTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1 YEAR' 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yearly, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.order_date >= '01-01-2011 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lifetime 
FROM reports AS r, "TypeOfFruits" AS tof 
WHERE r.id = tof."ID" 
GROUP BY "Fruits"
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN "Fruits" = 'Apple' THEN 1 
    WHEN "Fruits" = 'Pear' THEN 2 
    WHEN "Fruits" = 'Grapes' THEN 3 
    ELSE 4 
END
```

Results as of now

```
Fruits;daily;monthly;yearly;lifetime
"Apple";17;1174;3136;3136
"Pear";28;94;94;94
"Grapes";0;191;490;490
"Other";0;2;27;27
"Other";0;0;1;1
"Other";0;0;27;27
"Other";0;6;28;28
"Other";0;58;229;229
"Other";0;3;3;3
"Other";0;0;1;1
```

Desired results would be one row with the "Other" total, so four rows altogether
(x would be the total)

```
Fruits;daily;monthly;yearly;lifetime
"Apple";17;1174;3136;3136
"Pear";28;94;94;94
"Grapes";0;191;490;490
"Other";x;x;x;x
```

Comment: Why is Fruit misspelled as Friut 10 times?

Comment: ok I fixed the spelling issue (Dam you copy and paste) and updated the question a little

Comment: Good job, I like @Joe's answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY 1` to order by the first field, which is "Fruits". The same is valid for `GROUP BY`

**Update**

For the order, instead of doing the `case` in the `order by`, create a new column in.. say.. the second position:

```
(CASE 
    WHEN "Fruits" = 'Apple' THEN 1 
    WHEN "Fruits" = 'Pear' THEN 2 
    WHEN "Fruits" = 'Grapes' THEN 3 
    ELSE 4 ) as Order
```

Then in you `ORDER BY 2`.

Comment: This did help with the GROUP BY and I'm using @Joe Philllips ORDER BY, But the ORDER BY is now Alphabetical and not in the order I wanted, hence the numerical values in my example. +1

Comment: trying this but now it wants the GROUP BY tof."TypeOfFruits"

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this can be found in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY):

> Each expression [in the ORDER BY list] can be the name or ordinal number of an *output* column (SELECT list item), or it can be an arbitrary expression formed from *input*-column values.

(my emphasis)

The reason for this is that old versions of the SQL standard (SQL-92) only allowed sorting by output column name or number, whereas newer versions allow sorting by arbitrary expressions, but those expressions are formed from input column values.

Other answers already contain various suitable workarounds for your case.

Answer (score 2):

The alias is assigned after the order by so you can't use it in the order by. Use this instead:

```
(CASE
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'A' THEN 'Apple' 
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'P' THEN 'Pear' 
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'G' THEN 'Grapes' 
    ELSE 'Other' END)
```

Comment: if I remove the AS "Fruits" alias the GROUP by is off now, so I still have multiple rows of other. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you removing it? You can keep it but you can't reference it in a group by or order by clause

Comment: I'm using this in the ORDER BY w/ @Adrian GROUP BY 1 answer but now the ORDER BY is not in the order I desired. It's Alphabetical, any thoughts? +1

Answer (score 2):

Consider something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT (CASE
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'A' THEN 'Apple' 
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'P' THEN 'Pear' 
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'G' THEN 'Grapes' 
    ELSE 'Other' END) AS "Fruits", 
    (CASE 
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'A' THEN 1 
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'P' THEN 2 
    WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'G' THEN 3 
    ELSE 4 END) as NUM

        FROM ..... <rest of your query without group by and order by .....
    )

GROUP BY Fruits
ORDER BY NUM
```

Comment: I like this idea but it still wants the tof."TypeOfFruits" in the GROUP BY. ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias

Comment: Not sure why. Outer query should only need Fruits and NUM. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this ... untested, but I've seen similar queries.
Let me know if it works...

```
SELECT "Fruits",
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.order_date 
        BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('DAY', LOCALTIMESTAMP) AND DATE_TRUNC('DAY', LOCALTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1 DAY' 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS daily, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.order_date 
        BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', LOCALTIMESTAMP) AND DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', LOCALTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS monthly, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.order_date 
        BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', LOCALTIMESTAMP) AND DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', LOCALTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1 YEAR' 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yearly, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.order_date >= '01-01-2011 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lifetime 
FROM reports AS r
    ,(SELECT "ID",
             CASE
                WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'A' THEN 'Apple' 
                WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'P' THEN 'Pear' 
                WHEN tof."TypeOfFruits" = 'G' THEN 'Grapes' 
                ELSE 'Other'
             END AS "Fruits" FROM "TypeOfFruits" ) AS "tof"
WHERE r.id = tof."ID" 
GROUP BY "Fruits"
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN "Fruits" = 'Apple' THEN 1 
    WHEN "Fruits" = 'Pear' THEN 2 
    WHEN "Fruits" = 'Grapes' THEN 3 
    ELSE 4 
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using backticks (`) instead of single/double quotes to wrap your alias name.

Had the same issue with MySQL; backticks fixed the problem.

Comment: MySQL uses backticks, PostgreSQL uses double quotes, like in the SQL standard. MySQL is not standard compliant.