# Can't use alias in mysql function as part of ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

If I execute the following query it works fine.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN description LIKE '%a%' THEN 'A'
        WHEN description LIKE '%b%' THEN 'B'
        ELSE 'C'
    END AS foo
,COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM product p
GROUP BY foo
ORDER BY foo;
```

The result is something like

```
foo  |  cnt
-----------
A    |  809
B    |   29
C    |   55
```

However, the following query gives an error. Note that I only changed the last line.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN description LIKE '%a%' THEN 'A'
        WHEN description LIKE '%b%' THEN 'B'
        ELSE 'C'
    END AS foo
,COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM product p
GROUP BY foo
ORDER BY FIELD(foo, 'A', 'B', 'C');    -- Different line
```

> SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'foo' in 'order clause'

Why is that?

I'musing MySQL version 5.0.22

**UPDATE**:

just to expand, I see the same behaviour if I leave out the grouping, that is:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN description LIKE '%a%' THEN 'A'
        WHEN description LIKE '%b%' THEN 'B'
        ELSE 'C'
    END AS foo
FROM product p
ORDER BY foo;
```

(runs fine)

vs

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN description LIKE '%a%' THEN 'A'
        WHEN description LIKE '%b%' THEN 'B'
        ELSE 'C'
    END AS foo
FROM product p
ORDER BY FIELD(foo, 'A', 'B', 'C');    -- Different line
```

(error)

Comment: I can run your exact query in MySQL 5.6. What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why that happens is because MySQL was processing ORDER BY in earlier versions (apparently including 5.0) is the following way:

1. If the entire `ORDER BY` clause is an integer, sort by the corresponding element of the projection clause (`ORDER BY 2` sorts by the second element of the project clause)
2. If the entire `ORDER BY` clause is an identifier, search for a projection list element with such an alias, or, if none found, for a column with such a name, and sort by that.
3. Otherwise, parse the expression. Only column names, but not aliases, are visible during parsing.

So in your first query you get to the second case, hence you see the alias, in your second query you get to the third case, and hence do not see it.

UPDATE: Seems like PostgreSQL has exactly the same behavior. Look at answer by Peter Eisentraut here
[ [ORDER BY Alias not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458669/order-by-alias-not-working) ]

He summarizes the same thing I said, but for PostgreSQL. Order By can have either an alias (**output column**), or an integer, or an expression referencing **input columns**.

Comment: Thanks! Is that stated anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: I cannot locate any place in the MySQL documentation where they explicitly state it. I know it because I was playing with MySQL code before, and saw that behavior in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group by the alias then put your query in a derived table

```
SELECT foo, count(*) cnt FROM (
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN description LIKE '%a%' THEN 'A'
        WHEN description LIKE '%b%' THEN 'B'
        ELSE 'C'
    END AS foo
    FROM product p
) t1
GROUP BY foo
ORDER BY FIELD(foo, 'A', 'B', 'C');    -- Different line
```

Comment: I'm aware of this possibility, but the query in question (which is more complex than the example I posted) is generated dinamically, so I cannot just change its structure like that without working a lot on the code that generates it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error occures because you cannot use alias within the `field` method.

Use `1` insted of `foo`. Like this:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(1, 'A', 'B', 'C');    -- Different line
```

Comment: In which case `1` is of course an integer 1, not the first element of the projection clause

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ordinal position, you should be able to group by that such as..

```
select *
   from
      ( SELECT 
              CASE WHEN description LIKE '%a%' THEN 'A'
                   WHEN description LIKE '%b%' THEN 'B'
                   ELSE 'C' END AS foo
              ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM product p
           GROUP BY 1 ) PreQuery
   ORDER BY 
      FIELD(foo, 'A', 'B', 'C');
```

I know the order by might not work as it is part of a function, so I have wrapped it... OR, you would just need to have your dynamically constructed query build the case/when condition and have it pasted into each component

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN description LIKE '%a%' THEN 'A'
           WHEN description LIKE '%b%' THEN 'B'
           ELSE 'C' END AS foo
      ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM 
      product p
   GROUP BY 
      CASE WHEN description LIKE '%a%' THEN 'A'
           WHEN description LIKE '%b%' THEN 'B'
           ELSE 'C' END
   ORDER BY 
      FIELD( CASE WHEN description LIKE '%a%' THEN 'A'
                  WHEN description LIKE '%b%' THEN 'B'
                  ELSE 'C' END, 'A', 'B', 'C');
```